# Android ViewFlipper flip without animation

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm using ViewFlipper to flip views with animation. But is it to disable animation sometimes? I tried startFlipping() but failed. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just commenting out the **setInAnimation** and **setOutAnimation** and call showNext() or showPrevious() will do the trick:

```
            //viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
            //viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
            viewFlipper.showNext();
```

Final solution:

```
            viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(0);
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(null);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(null);
            viewFlipper.showNext();
```